# Simulate Mouse Click in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, unit-testing, mouseevent

I am working on an AS3 project and I am struggling with one particularly fragile part which will need a lot of refactoring in the near future. Just unit testing separate classes in isolation does not catch all issues we are running into. For example, we might forget to disable mouse events on a transparent overlay and thereby block all clicks on a button. Therefore, I am trying to write a test that simulates real user input.

I have tried to manually send a MouseEvent to the stage at the correct position:

```
stage.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK, true, true, 380, 490, stage));
```

Since the stage has no click event handler, I expected the event to propagate through the hierarchy to the button that will actually handle it (as it does when I physically click the mouse). However, it doesn't.

I know that I could just dispatch the event on the button, but that will not detect if the object is somehow obstructed. **Is there some way to simulate mouse events, such that they will properly propagate through the hierarchy?**

*Edit:*
I managed to do it by re-implementing the propagation behavior of Flash:

*Edit 2:*
My previous solution didn't work if there was a partly transparent overlay with a click handler, like a Sprite with a few Shapes in it. The problem is that the hitTestPoint method returns true even if the object in question is completely transparent at that point. Therefore, I modified it to check the actual pixel value:

```
private function clickObject(obj:DisplayObject) : void 
{
    var relPos:Point = new Point(obj.width / 2, obj.height / 2);
    var globalPos:Point = obj.localToGlobal(relPos);

    simulateClick(obj.stage, globalPos);
}

private function simulateClick(obj:InteractiveObject, globalPos:Point) : Boolean 
{
    // first, check if we have any children that would rather handle the event
    var container:DisplayObjectContainer = obj as DisplayObjectContainer;
    if (container != null) 
    {
        if (container.mouseChildren)
        {
            for (var i:int = 0; i < container.numChildren; ++i) 
            {
                var child:DisplayObject = container.getChildAt(i);
                var interactive:InteractiveObject = child as InteractiveObject;
                if (interactive != null) 
                {
                    if (simulateClick(interactive, globalPos)) 
                    {
                        // if we have found a handler in the children, we are done
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (!obj.mouseEnabled) {
        return false;
    }

    if (obj.hitTestPoint(globalPos.x, globalPos.y)) 
    {
        var localPos:Point = obj.globalToLocal(globalPos);

        // check if object is visible at the clicked location
        var pixel:BitmapData = new BitmapData(1, 1);
        pixel.draw(obj, new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -localPos.x, -localPos.y));
        var color:uint = pixel.getPixel32(0, 0);
        if ((pixel.getPixel32(0, 0) & 0xff000000) != 0)
        {
            // if yes, dispatch the click event
            var e:MouseEvent = new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK, true, true, localPos.x, localPos.y, obj);
            obj.dispatchEvent(e);
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Unfortunately, there is still at least one case not covered: If the object is a mask for another object. I have no idea how to check for this, since it could be mask anywhere in the display hierarchy. I would have to traverse the whole tree and check every single display object to find this out.

So, my question remains: **Isn't there an easier way to do this?**

Answer (score 2):

I've had issues with events in AS3 as well. I've found that the best way is to have the eventListeners added to the same object that's dispatching the events. In your case, adding the .addEventListener to the stage and sending the function as a function on a child clip. eg:

```
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, object.object.clicked);
```

I hope this may help. I've used this method with success in the past.

Comment: I cannot change the place where the event listeners are added, because I want to run tests on existing code. Apart from that, I don't think that putting all event handlers directly on the stage is a very scalable or maintainable approach...

Answer (score 1):

You can use **stage.getObjectsUnderPoint(new Point(pointerX , pointerY ));** function , that will return You array with objects . Than remove overlay object and last instance in array should be deepest DisplayObject.

note: last instance can be graphic or such thing , so You should loop through parent objects to find nearest InteractiveObject .
Also , dont forget that parent objects can have **mouseChildren = false** or **mouseEnabled = false**

Comment: I don't see how that solves my problem. The array returned by that function does not have any specific order, at least the docs do not specify any for it. So, I would still have to figure out the display order of these objects, which would basically boil down to what I already have.